# Scheme question smaller

Tags: scheme

The question requires me to Complete a function smaller, which consumes a string and produces a string. The consumed string consists only if numeric characters, which we will call digits (1-9,0). The produced string will consist of a string of length 1 (a single digit) obtained by repeatedly removing with the first or last digit in the string, depending on which is larger in value.

For example,

```
(smaller "5284")
=> (smaller "284")
=> (smaller "28")
=> (smaller "2")
=> "2"
```

If there is tie (between the first and last digit), remove the last one.

For example,

```
(smaller "131")
=> (smaller "13")
=> (smaller "1")
=> "1"
```

So how do I write the Scheme code for this question?
Thanks so much!

Comment: Which part of the task are you having trouble with? What hints have your lecture notes or textbook given you about this problem?

Answer (score 1):

What about something like this?

```
(define smaller
  (lambda (str)
    (cond
      [(= 1 (string-length str)) str]
      [(> (string-ref str 0) (string-ref str (- (string-length str) 1))) (smaller (substring str 0 (- (string-length str) 1)))]
      [else (smaller (substring str 1))])))
```

Comment: Please don't directly answer homework questions with the full solution. The poster learns nothing that way, and others end up trying to maintain the code they write later on. Have the poster show what they've tried so far, explain how it doesn't work, and give them pointers on how to figure out how to fix it. That way, they actually have to understand the solution and therefore learn something. Giving the answer doesn't provide any educational value. Thanks.

Comment: You're right. Sorry, I haven't seen the [homework] tag at first glance.

Comment: It probably wasn't there when you posted; I added it as an edit. You could tell it was homework, though, in the opening sentence: "The question requires me to Complete" and the phrasing of other things: "the consumed string", "which we will call", "obtained string", and the final paragraph which says "How do I write...for this question?". All obvious indicators of someone looking for homework answers. :)